Geocoding addresses with business names in R?
I am using the tidygeocoder package/Google API in R to geocode addresses. This is one example:
library(tidygeocoder)

example1<-tibble(address=c("107 W 6th St, Roswell, NM 88201"), business_name=c("Yoly’s Ice Cream"))
geocode(example1, address="address", method="google", full_results = TRUE)

When I am trying to geocode an address, I give the geocode function the address. However, suppose there is a business at that particular address. Is there anyway I can incorporate the name of the business at a particular address into the geocode function? I want to include BOTH the address info and the business name info. in the geocode function. I am trying to include as much info as possible in the geocode function.

Could you add an example of the address + business name you describe (if I'm understanding right that the example1 in your code block is not an address with a business name attached) and the expected output you want?

I can't test your code since geocode requires a Google API key, but looking at the examples given on the official doco, the geocode function will simply append any geocoding info found back to the supplied tibble/tribble. In your case you will simply get back your own business_name column. Now if the argument full_results is set to TRUE, you may get some useful columns such as office and tourism (if there are any valid data for those columns)

@JayBee I'm going to edit my question in a minute to hopefully clarify it; I think the way I phrased it originally isn't very clear

@JayBee I just edited it; here is what I was trying to say: suppose there is an address, like 100 New York St, New York, NY; at this address there is a business called "McDonald." Is it possible to give both the business' name and the address to the geocode function? I am trying to give as much info as possible to the geocoder

Based on Google's Geocoding API documentation, this doesn't seem possible since the API only considers address components, lat/lon coordinates or place ID as valid input parameters. The geocoding results do return the place ID for you, which you can then pass to the Places API, which may match the business name info you have, but you'll likely need to write your own functions to do that (using httr2 for instance).

@cristian-vargas thank you for the information!
